# How can you create a docker image using a folder on a network drive?

Tags: docker

I will start by saying I am a complete newbie to docker. I have created a docker image for a project locally, but other people in our organization will need to do the same thing. Instead of having them copy the folder locally, **I would want them to able to create the image on the folder on our network drive.**

I can't seem to cd into the network drive - do anybody know of any guides to do what the question asks, or perhaps give a brief explanation of what I should be searching for (I have tried searching online, but can't seem to find a guide on how to create a docker image on a network folder, perhaps I'm using the wrong terminology)?

Comment: The result of building an image (i.e. THE image) does not go into a folder but in your local docker daemon registry. If you need to share that image, you probably want to build it, tag it and push it, possibly with some CI workflow, to a remote registry (e.g. dockerhub, docker registry, nexus repository, artifactory, gitlab registry.....) where people in your team will be able to pull it. If you really need people to build the image themselves, you should put your dockerfile and ressources under version control (e.g. git) and have people clone the repo prior to launch the build.

Comment: The minimal answer is to put the image's `Dockerfile` in the network folder, `cd` there, and run `docker build` as usual; the Docker daemon doesn't know that the source happens to be a network drive.

Comment: `I can't seem to cd into the network drive` What does the path to the network drive look like?